# How to extract this numerical value from the text file in unix

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I want to extract the value of `VALUE_ID` in the below text and store it in a variable.

```
MSG : SUCCESS! ABCDEFGHIJK
VALUE_ID: 775
```

Please note that there is a space after `:` in `VALUE_ID`.

Can we use awk for this or is there any easier way?

Comment: you've been asking many similar questions. Accept some of the answer and use them for this one. This is not a coding service

Comment: Ok.. Actually I was about to select the answers

Comment: `grep -oP 'VALUE_ID:\h*\K.*'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With **awk:**

```
var=$(awk '$1 == "VALUE_ID:" {print $2}' File)
```

Inside `awk`script, we check if the first field in the line is `VALUE_ID:`. if yes, print the value field which will be seperated by space. This output is saved to the bash variable `var`, which will contain `775`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

```
awk '$1 == "VALUE_ID:" {id=$2}' input_file
```

This seems fairly pointless to me. If you describe your needs more precisely the I could help you better.

Comment: Actually i want the value of 775 to be stored inside a variable say VAR1.

Comment: @ramaswamy: Ok, but in [tag:awk] or in a [tag:bash] environment variable. Where is the input comes from? From a file or from a stream?